# Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Tags: android

I have file `/FavoriteTwitterSearches/res/menu/FavoriteTwitterSearches.xml` in my android project. When I want to run the project - i get error **"res\menu\FavoriteTwitterSearches.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]"**. But if I change the file name for a-z,0-9 there is another errors in `/R.java/R/string/confi` 
like

Multiple markers at this line

```
- Duplicate field R.string.confi
- Syntax error on token "rmTitle", delete
```

or 
Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error on token "rmMessage", delete 
 this token
```

Comment: check for duplicate string inputs

Comment: clean your project....

Comment: Which lines of code give the last two sets of errors?

Answer (score 4):

"res\menu\FavoriteTwitterSearches.xml:  the res folder accepts only small case letters 
change your file name to

favoritetwittersearches and it will work

Comment: More correctly, as the error says, the filename must only contain [a-z0-9_.], meaning lowercase alpha characters, numerals, underscores, and periods.

Answer (score 0):

Capital letters are not allowed in naming any .xml files. using it will give you an error.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: The error : Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.] itself makes it LOUD N CLEAR !!!

Comment: The error says the _file name_ can not contain capitals, you claim that the _file_ can not contain capitals.

Comment: So "AndroidManifest.xml" is illegal? This is not a correct answer. XML files in the res folder may not.

Comment: HAHA! Somebody here is new to Android. The Manifest file has always been an exception. I verified this and MY ANSWER IS SUPPER GREAT AND CORRECT!!! Below I shall paste the truth!!!                           

[2014-03-17 13:24:00 - HomeActivity] res\layout\myTest: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-17 13:24:00 - HomeActivity] C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Android-Universal-Image-Loader-master\Android-Universal-Image-Loader-master\sample\res\layout\myTest:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found

Comment: To be exact, any files inside `/res` folder cannot have capital letters. You can have capital letter inside `/assets` folder without any care.